# Vue Fetch Data from API

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vue, There is only blank data coming to my table after I have used Vue and Axios to pass data to a table on my website. I am not sure if it is the way the data coming from the API is structured.

```
3{
    "body": [
        {
            "id": "17",
            "company": "Vooxoo",
            "mobile": null,
            "logo": "2.jpg",
            "opening_hours": "",
            "featured_vendor": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "company": "Trendo Designs",
            "mobile": null,
            "logo": "4.jpg",
            "opening_hours": "Mo - Fr: 10:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
            "featured_vendor": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "company": "",
            "mobile": null,
            "logo": "",
            "opening_hours": "",
            "featured_vendor": "No"
        }
    ],
    "itemCount": 3
}
```

My Vue code is also seems to be correct, I can see the data logged into my console.

```
<script>
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            vendors: []
          },
          mounted:  function(){
           axios.get('https://myapi.com/API/api/read_all_api.php')
              .then(response => {
                this.vendors = response;
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
 
        })
    </script>
```

And Finally my html looks like this, I have added Vue and Axios in the header tag.

```
                            <div id="app" class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm v-middle" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="bg-light">
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Company</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Mobile Number Agent</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Opening Hours</th>
                                            <th class="border-top-0">Status</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr v-for="vendor in vendors">
                                            <td> {{ vendor.company }} </td>
                                            <td> {{ vendor.mobile }} </td>
                                            <td> {{ vendor.opening_hours }} </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <label class="label label-danger">{{ vendor.featured_vendor }}</label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have changed the code in several ways but I am not too sure what exactly the problem is. I need help.

Comment: Please don't use 2 different accounts to [post the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736768/my-data-from-an-api-through-axios-and-displayed-with-vue-is-not-showing)

Comment: My other account have been blocked, I am not sure why. And  if you read the question carefully, you will see it's not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to open `data` like `response.data` <--- your data is inside `data`
do

```js
mounted:  function(){
           axios.get('https://myapi.com/API/api/read_all_api.php')
              .then(response => {
                this.vendors = response.data; // <--- here
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }this.vendor
```

Comment: When I do that, nothing shows up at all in the table, I had that as a question here first.  [Here is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736768/my-data-from-an-api-through-axios-and-displayed-with-vue-is-not-showing) .